# align div on bottom of another div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

here is the css/html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
#chatContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.chat {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0px;
    transition: 1s;
}
.title {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
.text {
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 120px;
}
.inputText {
    width: 100%
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chatContainer">
  <div class="chat" id="{id}">
    <div class="title"> <span>{title}</span>
      <div style="float:right">
        <input  class="minimize" name="" value="min" type="button">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text"> </div>
    <div class="chatbox">
      <input type="text" class="inputText"  placeholder="enter text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat" id="{id}" style="height:100px">
    <div class="title"> <span>{title}</span>
      <div style="float:right">
        <input  class="minimize" name="" value="min" type="button">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text"> </div>
    <div class="chatbox">
      <input type="text" class="inputText"  placeholder="enter text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I want the chatbox to be aligned on bottom
Here is now the bad result I got:
[image]

Any idea how to fix that ?

(I tried vertical-align with no success)

I have created the  fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uwmxT/

(click on min to see the bug)

Comment: make a fiddle so i can update your code :) then i can come with a solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EXrnB/5/ try out this fiddle it should do the trick

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uwmxT/ : see min to reproduce the bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use float:right but display:inline-box on your chat boxes and vertical-align them to the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/SfnrU/2/

```
.chat {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width to following id of css :

```
#chatContainer {
    bottom: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 265px;  // added width
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7gEfL/1/

Answer (score 0):

set the box css position to absolute and add to it basic positioning commands to css style

```
#id_chat{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:250px; /*width of your very right chat box, + you can add e.g. 10px as margin*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ueE4b/1/

Comment: Not bad.. My problem is chats are going to be added dynamically.
So right:250px is not good enough !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hanakivan/uwmxT/5/ is that what you want?
Your bug was caused by not setting margin-top while decreasing the height of the element.

And to my answer, you obviously add those chats through JS, so why not calculate position as well?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty simple i just made a fiddle which shows a fixed positioned chatbox

with a input area in the bottom of it

i made a innerholder to make sure it works in all browsers

[**See this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EXrnB/5/) to see the code

code:

```
<div class="chat">
  <div class="innerchat">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="start chatting" />
  </div>
</div>

.chat {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position:fixed;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
}
.chat .innerchat {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;    
}
.chat .innerchat .textbox {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  background:#ccc;
  color:#404040;
  height:30px;
  text-indent:6px;
}
```

enjoy